# overflow:scroll masked under div

Tags: css, overflow

I have to make an ecommerce website and I've reached the part when I have  to load the products on the page. As you can see, this doesn't happen properly. I've tried with 'overflow' property but it didn't work. The first row of products it's 'under' the div parent.

This is what's like without overflow
[image: This is how the page looks without overflow property enabled]

This is what's like with 'overflow:scroll;'
[image: This is how it looks with overflow property enable]

> 

```
<div id="rightPanel">
    {% for row in queryResult %}
    <script>
    var productPhone = document.createElement('div');
    var rightPanel = document.getElementById("rightPanel");

    var name = document.createElement('div');
    var photo = document.createElement('div');
    var price = document.createElement('div');
    var button = document.createElement('div');

    productPhone.setAttribute("class","productPhone");
    name.setAttribute("class","namePhone");
    name.innerHTML = "Telefon {{row.brand}} {{ row.product_name }}";
    photo.setAttribute("class","photoPhone");
    price.setAttribute("class","pricePhone");
    price.innerHTML = "{{ row.price }}";
    button.setAttribute("class","buttonPhone");
    button.innerHTML = "<a href='{{ PHPpath }}/productTemplate.php?id={{ row.id }}'> 
    <i class='fas fa-angle-double-right'></i>Details</a>";

    productPhone.appendChild(photo);
    productPhone.appendChild(name);
    productPhone.appendChild(price);
    productPhone.appendChild(button);
    rightPanel.appendChild(productPhone);
    </script>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

And this is the corresponding CSS code:

> 

```
    #rightPanel
    {
        width: 70%;
        height: 1000px;
        border: 1px solid black;

        position: absolute;
        top: 200px;
        left: 27%;

        overflow: scroll;
        clear: both;
        white-space: nowrap;

        margin-bottom: 20px;

        display:flex!important;
        justify-content: flex-start!important;
        align-items: flex-start!important;
        align-content: center!important;
        flex-flow: row wrap!important;

    }

.productPhone
{
    border: 1px solid red;

    width: 200px;
    height: 280px;

    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;

    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;

}
```

I really don't understand why it behaves like this..

Comment: any fiddle link?  try giving z-index value

Comment: Thank you, but I tried with z-index

Comment: it worked; good.